# Access attributes of a different screen

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

How do I access `img_path` and `img`  attributes of class(screen) `E1` inside `Guide`? I'm doing it currently as shown in the code below, but it throws an error saying `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`.

I read a number of answers on this and figured that I have to declare these as `StringProperty()` maybe, but they all had a separate `.kv` file where they defined the screens so I couldn't figure out how to do the same with my piece of code.

```
class E1(GridLayout):
    ...
    ...
    self.img_path = "./Images/e1.jpg"
    self.img = Image(source = self.img_path)
    ...
    ...

class GuideOP(GridLayout):
    ...
    ...
    self.img_path = app.screen_manager.get_screen("E1").ids.img_path.get()
    self.img = app.screen_manager.get_screen("E1").ids.img.get()
    ...
    ...

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.e1_page = E1()
        screen = Screen(name = "E1")
        screen.add_widget(self.e1_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        self.guide_page = GuideOP()
        screen = Screen(name = "GuideOP")
        screen.add_widget(self.guide_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using a `kv` file, then you cannot use `ids`. That is likely the source of the error message.

Assuming that

```
self.guide_page = GuideOP()
```

is actually meant to use the

```
class Guide(GridLayout)
```

Then, I think you can try:

```
self.img_path = app.screen_manager.get_screen("E1").children[0].img_path
self.img = app.screen_manager.get_screen("E1").children[0].img
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should work. Note that the `E1` `Widget` is a child of the `Screen` named `E1`. Thus the use of `children[0]`. This assumes that there are no other `children` of that `Screen`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't actually know about the children of a screen, so that was the trouble.